# How to generate series in php with number gets multipled by 6 after every 2 numbers

Tags: php, numbers

I am thinking of an algorithm by which I can generate a sequence where, for 1000 numbers, every 3rd number is multiplied by 6. A sample output is like this:

```
1
2
6
4
5
12
7
8
18
10
11
24
13
14
30
16
17
36
19
20
```

Comment: 1) Your sample sequence doesn't match your specification. 2) What have you tried so far and what errors / problems did you have? 3) Why did you include the `random` tag?

Comment: It's not every 2 numbers, it's actually every 3rd number. In fact, it's every number (in an array) that is located at `(i+1) % 3 == 0` where `i` is the index of the number. Simply check your indexes for the above statement and multiply that value by 2.

Comment: Every number divisible by 3 is multiplied by 6?

Comment: @rjmunro By 2 I would say.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have tried fiboncci,factorial to generate numbers.But i am not getting the clue how can write a php script to generate such numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
function getNumber($i) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        return $i * 2;
    } else {
        return $i;
    }
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
    echo getNumber($i) . "\n";
}
```

Or, inline:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
    echo ($i % 3 ? $i : $i * 2) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: I tried the same but its not generating anything

Comment: @user3403027 Wrap it in a for loop or something.  `for ($i = 1; $i<20 ; $i++) { echo getNumber($i) . "\n"; }`

Comment: 1 2 6 4 5 12 7 8 18 10 11 24 13 14 30 16 17 36 19 20 such sequence i want to generate till 1000.After 2 digit, number is multiplied by 6..so on.The problem i m facing is its not generating any sequence..